# How to reload browser and and keep current state in AngularJS UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I built a small web app where I use UI-Router to navigate its pages. Everything works fine apart of the browser refresh or accessing the specific page using the state link. I tried several solutions posted here on the same topic but non of them helped maybe due to lack of additional information.

When I click the ui-sref link below, I get 'mysite/content' and page displays normally, but once I refresh it or try to access by just pasting the link it doesn't find the page.

Could you please help to me to make it work as expected. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<p ui-sref="content">Link To Content</p>
```

AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider, $locationProvider){


    $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/');


    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/wrapper.html'},
                'nav@home': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/nav.html'},
                'header@home': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/header.html'},
                'footer@home': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/footer.html'}
            }
        })

        .state('content', {
            url: '/content',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/content.html'},
                'nav@content': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/nav.html'},
                'header@content': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/header.html'},
                'footer@content': { templateUrl: '/app/templates/footer.html'}

            }
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


}])
```

Comment: Do you have any data that needs to be resolved before the page loads ? Maybe your app data is not loaded ...

Comment: currently the app is completely empty. Now I noticed that if I set the $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) to false it works as expected but with the dash in the link. trying to solve it

Answer (score 0):

With html5Mode set to true, when refreshing the page, your browser will make a request to 'mysite/content'. In classical one-page-applications, your back-end has a set of routes that respond some data, and it is usually configured to return the application index.html for all the other routes (for example 'mysite/content').

It works when you disable html5Mode because the browser makes a request to the url without the part after the '#', for which your back-end most certainly returns the expected index.html.